# How do I access content in a script tag using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and I'm trying to use beautiful soup to find a script tag on a page that has the dataLayer and then retrieve the value of postNo and print it.

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Data Layer - Begin -->
<script>
  dataLayer = [
    {
      'country': 'UnitedKingdom',
      'site': 'Blog',
      'postNo': '34',
      'pageType': 'Home',
      'pageType2': 'Blog',
      'pageType3': 'Top Tips'
    }
  ];
</script>
<!-- Data Layer - End -->
  </head>
```

Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: is that EXACTLY how the html is in the page source?

Comment: No the dataLayer is in different places on different type of pages. At some pages in the head and at some pages in the body, so it will not be the 3rd script in all pages.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I'm seeing that the key values `country`, `site`, etc. DO NOT have the double quotes around them. In the page source, do those keys NOT have double quotes?

Comment: apologies, the VS code formatter might have changed.
yes the key and value both have sigle quotes.

<code>
    <!-- Data Layer - Begin -->
    <script>
        dataLayer = [{
            'country': 'UnitedKingdom',
            'site': 'Blog',
            'articleID': '34',
            'pageType': 'Home',
            'pageType2': 'Blog',
            'pageType3': 'Top Tips'

        }];
    </script>
    <!-- Data Layer - End -->
</code>

Comment: ok cool. that actually makes it easier. will have your solution in a minute or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import bs4
import json




html = '''
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Data Layer - Begin -->
<script>
  dataLayer = [
    {
      'country': 'UnitedKingdom',
      'site': 'Blog',
      'postNo': '34',
      'pageType': 'Home',
      'pageType2': 'Blog',
      'pageType3': 'Top Tips'
    }
  ];
</script>
<!-- Data Layer - End -->
  </head>'''


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'dataLayer = ' in script.text:

        jsonStr = script.text.strip()
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('[')[1].strip()
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split(']')[0].strip()
        jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("'", '"')

        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

print (jsonObj['postNo'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonObj['postNo'])
34
```

Comment: hi @chitown88 , thanks a ton for helping on this one mate but i am not getting the output for some reason. Tried changing the indentation too

Comment: ah shoot. I had a typo. Fixed it above. Try again

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the list from the html and parse, simple. See the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ast
html = '''
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Data Layer - Begin -->
<script>
  dataLayer = [
    {
      'country': 'UnitedKingdom',
      'site': 'Blog',
      'postNo': '34',
      'pageType': 'Home',
      'pageType2': 'Blog',
      'pageType3': 'Top Tips'
    }
  ];
</script>
<!-- Data Layer - End -->
  </head>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.findAll('script')[2].text.replace(';','').replace('dataLayer = ','').strip()
data = ast.literal_eval(content)
print([x['postNo'] for x in data])
```